# python import hooks: accessing the full dotted module name before processing

Tags: python

I understand the fact that the importer protocol operates at the level of individual imports. However, in my case, it would be really helpful if I could know the full "dotted module name" BEFORE fully experiencing it one path element at time (that is, "a priori" if I'm allowed to say that) from my import hook.

```
class myimporter(object):
    def find_module(self,fullname,path=None):
        if fullname == 'rootnamespace':
            #at this moment I need to know the full dotted module name
            #that I am going to process (e.g. rootnamespace.foo.bar.baz)

    def load_module(self,fullname):
         pass
```

Is there a way (hopefully safe and sound) to know beforehand the full "dotted module name" from within an import hook?

---

--- more infos, probably not really needed (so you can skip straight to answering me ;) ), however:

If the reader wonders why would I need that or just maybe a little bit more info is to be helpful: I want to import perl modules in python. How strange does this sound? :) In reality, the import process will just make available a python stub for a perl module. The stub is generated by introspecting the perl package and see what it has to offer; I wont enter in the details of implementation here:

```
import perlmod.www.mechanize as wwwmech
mymech = wwwmech() #return a python proxy object to be used with later calls
mymech.get(uri) #returns another proxy object to the newly generated HTTP::Response perl object
#etc etc
```

my problem lies at

```
import perlmod.www.mechanize
```

because I need to know beforehand if the requested module does really exist in the system's perl installation, without being forced to wait the full module name so I can take the decision if I should fail or not. Moreover, if the user does:

```
import perlmod.www
```

I have no chance to get back and say "wait wait wait, this is wrong" after loading a www stub package. My hook won't be called after that.

Basically, when my import hook is called for "www" I must already know if the import will fail or succeed for the full dotted module name. I will stop here with the details, please don't forget the real question :)

Thank you very much, even only for reading this.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but have you come across the Parrot VM? It aims to allow reuse of code between dynamic languages, including Perl and Python. http://www.parrot.org/

Comment: yes I know parrot and its usefullness. cheers.

Comment: call it "my weekend project". I'm a sysadmin and most of my scripting was done in perl until few months ago when I suddenly migrated to python for various reasons; I still want to be able to elegantly reuse some of my perl old (or new) code. And what's more important, I really need the ACME:: perl goodies :P I don't want to carry a parrot with me for this as long as my snake can have the guts of a camel and can still be able to eat little children ;) code reuse taken to the next level

Comment: It's a clever idea, but you might need to go with a more explicit syntax, like `mechanize = perlimporter.load("www.mechanize")`. (mechanize in fact has been ported to Python if that makes your life easier: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ )

Comment: 10x thomas; wwwmech was just a sample that came to my mind for unknown reasons; re, explicit syntax: you must love syntactic sugar hence import perlmod.acme.kittens or thinking of the case "use POSIX qw/setsid/" which is best translated into "from perlmod.POSIX import setsid"

Comment: Syntactic sugar is neat, but I wouldn't spend much time over it if it's going to be difficult to implement.

Comment: I hear ya; maybe I should just remove the details :)